# Output shows all 0's. The gross and OT is not calculating

Tags: c

Output shows all 0's. The gross and OT is not calculating..

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define STD_HOURS 40.0
#define OT_RATE 1.5
#define SIZE 5


void read_hours(float worked_hours[], long int clockNumber[]);
void calculate_gross(float wage[], float worked_hours[], float gross);
void calculate_gross_ot(float wage[], float worked_hours[]);
void printFunction(long int clockNumber[], float wage[], float worked_hours[], float OT[],              float gross);

int i;



int main()
{

    long int clockNumber [SIZE] = {98401, 526488, 765349, 34645, 127615};/* employee ID */
    float gross = 0.0; /* gross */
    float OT [SIZE] = {}; /* overtime */
    float wage [SIZE] = {10.6, 9.75, 10.5, 12.25, 8.35};      /* hourly wage */
    float worked_hours [SIZE] = {};    //  Hours  worked


    read_hours(worked_hours, clockNumber);

    if (worked_hours[i]>STD_HOURS)
    {

    calculate_gross_ot(wage, worked_hours);

    }

    else

    {
       calculate_gross(wage,worked_hours, gross);

    }
    printFunction(clockNumber, wage, worked_hours, OT, gross);

    return(0);
}



void read_hours(float worked_hours[], long int clockNumber[])
{



    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {

        printf("\n Enter Hours for Emlployee ID: %ld\n", clockNumber[i]);
        scanf ("%f", &worked_hours[i]);

    }


}

void calculate_gross(float wage[], float worked_hours[], float gross)
{


    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)

        gross=(wage[i]*worked_hours[i]);
}


void calculate_gross_ot(float wage[], float worked_hours[])
{


    float gross;
    float OT[SIZE];

    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {



        /* calculating overtime hours */
           OT[i]=worked_hours[i]-STD_HOURS;

            /* calculating gross pay with overtime */
            gross = (STD_HOURS*wage[i]) + (OT[i]*OT_RATE*wage[i]);
        //}

    }

}

void printFunction(long int clockNumber[], float wage[], float worked_hours[], float OT[], float gross)
    {


        /* creating a table for the output */
        printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("%7s","Clock#");
        printf("%7s","Wages");
        printf("%7s","Hours");
        printf("%7s","OT");
        printf("%7s\n","Gross");
        printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)

{
        /* printing the results */
        printf("%6ld", clockNumber[i]);
        printf("%10.2f",wage[i]);
        printf("%6.1f", worked_hours[i]);
        printf("%6.1f", OT[i]);
        printf("%10.2f",gross);
        printf("\n");

 }


    }
```

The program is used to calculate gross with and without OT hours. The output is showing      all 0's for the gross and OT. Please help to figure out where is the mistake.

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is designed to help you solve problems, not fix your mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you are passing `gross` by value.

In the second case, you are not passing it at all (the function has a local function called `gross`).

In both cases, whenever the respective function changes `gross`, this change does not propagate to the caller.

You need to either pass `gross` by pointer, or return the value from the function using the `return` statement (and changing the return type appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

Pass `OT` to your `calculate_gross_ot()` function from `main()`.

```
 ...
 calculate_gross_ot(wage, worked_hours, OT);
 ...


 void calculate_gross_ot(float wage[], float worked_hours[], float OT[])
```